# HTML page fetched by Axios differs from browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, axios

I am trying to fetch the HTML content of [this page](https://www.google.com/search?q=taco+bell+mercer+st+seattle) using Axios. I noticed that the HTMl string returned differs from what I see when I access the website in browser. Specifically, there is a panel on the right side of the page that contains restaurant information, and the HTML for this is missing from what Axios returns. I assume this HTML is activated by a script? How can I get that portion of the page?

Comment: If it's added by script, you may need to do some rendering / executing arbitrary javascript. Have u tried instead of fetching with axios to just load the page with a headless browser (nightmare, chromium)?

Comment: You'd have to use something like https://www.cypress.io/, axios will only get you the server response, to get a modified document object model, client side js would need to be parsed and executed (modifying the dom), after which you would want your code to get a snapshot of the DOM.

Comment: Is it possible that the returned response differs by User-Agent?